# Why have we become so quick to migrate to BH.SE?

Tags: discussion, migration

I've noticed that lately we've very quickly moved quit a lot of question about the interpretation of a specific passage to BH.SE.  Specifically, [this question](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/19899/according-to-genesis-322-god-knows-evil-what-does-that-mean), which seemed unclear in its desire, was quickly moved today.  Do we really want to be moving questions to BH just because they ask about a specific passage?

Answer (score 8):

I apparently read the question rather differently than you did. Besides probably not speaking English as a first language and some formatting issues it seemed like a very obvious question of "what does this word refer to in this verse". That is a question pattern that works on BH just fine and does not at all on C.SE.

Furthermore my experience is different than yours in this:

> If they want an answer from theology (which is probably most of the time)

I would say that much of the time an answer from theology will serve them best, but that isn't what they expect. Most people are unaware of the frameworks that such questions require. Generally when asking about the meaning of a specific verse they *expect* to just get answers arguing fro what the *right* interpretation is. They are clueless as to how hard this is or why such questions are nearly impossible to scope.

On the other hand that's exactly the question format that BH is setup to handle. This wasn't a very well researched question, but the pattern suggested to me if it stood any hope of surviving its best shot would be on BH and CSE was a lost cause. Given the choice of closing outright and essentially telling him his question couldn't be asked without a ton of research and narrowing on his part I punted to the site that could handle the question as written.

I don't argue that the most meaningful treatments (and as a pastor what I really think he needs to here) is some theological framework with which to process reality, but this guy doesn't seem to be even close to asking the right question and the question I would have liked to answer (and I suspect that would turn into if left open on C.SE) is a truth question that's going to devolve into a battle over the nature of good and evil and God's relation to them. Not pretty and not constructive for this format.

That's roughly the thought process that went through my head reviewing that post. To answer your question about "why so fast", the answer is simply because somebody flagged it, I read it and it made perfect sense in my head. If it turns out I was reading it wrong and the OP's question is different we can re-evaluate and even move it back. But at first blush I didn't even see a hint of it working on CSE better so gave it what I thought was the best shot it had at survival.

Comment: Like, I said I think it is fundamentally an English question - the OP simply misunderstood what "knowing good and evil" means...  The bigger issue is the tendency seems to be "this doesn't request a tradition, so let's move it to BH."  That type of question is indeed a bad question for C.SE, but its bad on BH.SE too.  A truth question doesn't cease to be a truth question because it changed sites.

Comment: @ThaddeusB I picked up on the language issue to but assumed they hand really gotten hung up on the real theological issue (possibly in their own language first) and only came here to ask the question about it and had a hard time expressing it. That question would have to be asked on BH. If you are right and they didn't even get that far and were struggling to comprehend the English then the answer is really simple and could be answered on either site.

Comment: @ThaddeusB Another good reason for speed is that if the Q looks wrong, then [the faster closed/moved, the better](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92638/203418). I found the argument and reasoning of that Meta.SE post compelling. If in the end it proves precipitate, it can always be re-opened. But easier to keep junk off than deal with messes. (Or so I've come to think.)

Comment: @ThaddeusB I don't understand why you think that questions about the meaning of phrases don't belong at BH.

Comment: @curiousdannii I interpreted the question as asking about the theological implications of the text, which would make it a C.SE question.  But, mostly I don't think it is wise to move unclear questions - it is better to simply close them.

Answer (score -1):

It is only appropriate to move when the questioner clearly wants a "authorial intent reason".  If they want an answer from theology (which is probably most of the time), then it is inappropriate to migrate.  If it is unclear what they want, we should ask first.

IMO, this specific example was an especially poor candidate to move.  First, the question was rather unclear what it wanted. (I have edited it to make it clear.)  Indeed, it probably could have been closed for that reason.  Moving a question when its intent it not clear seems like a really bad idea.  Second, the question seems to be a "nature of God" type question, which is a theology question.  (OK, so its probably based on a misunderstanding of English as the OP is not a native speaker, and there doesn't seem to be any real conflict in the verse.  Still, it is much more on the theology side of things than the authorial intent side of things.)

Comment: If the intent was unclear then I'd agree with some of this, but I didn't think the intent was unclear at all and so acted on how I read it. I also disagree about what people tend to expect when asking about words in verses on CSE. I could turn out to be wrong, but for now I just plain disagree with this conclusion.

Comment: @Caleb Naturally, I could be the one who was mistaken here...  Let's see what others think.  (I invited BH chat regulars to weigh in as well.)

Comment: Both answers to that question interpreted it in theological terms. Whether or not they were good answers, this suggested that the question was a theological one and belongs in Christianity.